# How to solve docker-compose buld error while installing saleor?

Tags: docker-build, pnpm, saleor, peer-dependencies

Runnung `docker-compose build`, I get this error.
I have installed pnpm using `npm install -g pnpm` but still the same error occurs.

```
=> ERROR [saleor-platform_react-storefront 8/9] RUN pnpm install                                 
=> [saleor-platform_dashboard 4/5] RUN npm install 
=> CANCELED [saleor-platform_api build-python 5/5] RUN pip install -r requirements_dev.txt
```

Where do I edit the peer dependencies settings from?

```
Peer dependencies that should be installed:                                         -dependencies" setting to "false".   
#0 108.6   graphql-tag@^2.0.0                                                                -dependenc
#0 108.6
#0 108.6 hint: If you want peer dependencies to be automatically installed, set the "auto-install-peers" setting to "true".
#0 108.6 hint: If you don't want pnpm to fail on peer dependency issues, set the "strict-peer-dependencies" setting to "false".
#0 108.6
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pnpm install]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to the **react-storefront/Dockerfile.dev**

```
RUN npm install -g pnpm@6.32.11
```

Before the this line

```
RUN pnpm install
```

And run build/up again.

Source: https://github.com/saleor/saleor/issues/9764#issuecomment-1127050108